# Problem in dialing call with Twilio Voice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-twiml

I've made a back-end call and i want to trasfer it to front end to get the client device. The problem is that whenever i try to call i just get a Twilio voice demo response without being able to dial the call.

Im using Twilio Voice 1.x

```
 var toPhoneNumber = "+39********";

 TwilioClient.Init(model.AccountsId, model.Apitoken);


 var response = new VoiceResponse();
 var dial = new Dial();
 dial.Number(toPhoneNumber.ToString());  
 response.Append(dial);


 var call = CallResource.Create(
     to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(/*model.ToPhoneNumber*/ toPhoneNumber),
     from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(model.FromPhoneNumber),
     twiml: response.ToString()
 );



 model.CallsId = call.Sid;


 var grant = new VoiceGrant();
 grant.OutgoingApplicationSid = model.twilioAppSid;

 // Optional: add to allow incoming calls
 grant.IncomingAllow = true;

 var grants = new HashSet<IGrant>
 {
     { grant }
 };

 var token = new Twilio.Jwt.AccessToken.Token(model.AccountsId, model.apiKeySid, model.apiKeySecret, model.CallsId, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), null, grants: grants );

 model.AccessToken = token.ToJwt();
```

And there is my front-end code:

```
 <script>

     Twilio.Device.setup("@Model.AccessToken", {debug : true});

      function joinCall(callSid) {
          Twilio.Device.connect({
              callSid: callSid,
              To: @Model.ToPhoneNumber,
                
          });
      }

     
     var callSid = "@Model.CallsId"; 

      window.onload = joinCall(callSid);
 </script>
```

Here is my result on console: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/szINl.png)

Comment: This is a question for Twilio support. It may not be a code or programming question at all, which would mean it is off-topic for StackOverflow.